# Can I hide the sync icon in the menu bar on Lion?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, menu-bar

This menu bar icon is useless and takes up space.

[image: Sync icon]

I use iCloud on Mac OS X Lion to sync contacts, calendars, and the like. On Snow Leopard I could use an option in the iSync preferences to remove this icon from my menu bar, but iSync isn't around anymore. Is there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: To get it back, open Terminal.app and type `open /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/Sync.menu`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-Drag & Drop it away from the menu bar, this way you can also re-arrange your icons. This trick will only work for OSX icons (e.g. Time Machine or WiFi), for non OSX native icons (e.g. Dropbox or GeekTool) you need a third party app like [Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com) or [Menu Bar Rearranger](http://www.seense.com/mbra/).

Comment: Same here! It took up some really valuable menu bar real-estate.

Comment: works just as great on ML

Comment: Cmd click/drag also works for your folder navigations icons.

Comment: Great tip. How would you get it back if you wanted it?

Answer (score 1):

That sync icon is also used by MobileMe and another way to get rid of it is to log out of mobileme after migrating to iCloud (System Preferences/MobileMe). I had the same question and finally logged out of mobileme (which wasn't being used anymore) and it disappeared.